# TensorFlow Mean Squared Error metric always returns 0

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, statistics

I am encountering a problem where no matter what labels/predictions I pass TF.Metrics.Mean_Squared_Error it always returns a 0 value.

Here is code that duplicates the problem:

```
a = tf.constant([0,0,0,0])
b = tf.constant([1,1,1,1])
mse, update = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(a,b)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
mse.eval(session=sess)
```

%% returns 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why it works that way, but you actually need to run `update` before the inner state of the mse takes your data into account:

```
a = tf.constant([0,0,0,0])
b = tf.constant([1,1,1,1])
mse, update = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(a,b)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
mse.eval(session=sess) # Gives 0.0, the initial MSE value
update.eval(session=sess) # Gives 1.0, the value of the update for the mse
mse.eval(session=sess)  # Gives 1.0, which is 0.0+1.0, the updated mse value
```

`tf.metrics.mean_squared_error()` is meant to compute the MSE on a whole dataset for instance, so you should not be using it if you want the result for batches independantly. For that, use [`tf.losses.mean_squared_error(a, b, loss_collection=None)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error) for instance.

Comment: So if I wanted to get an mse for each batch of data, do I need to reset it somehow?  I.e. return to 0 and then add nonzero updates?

Comment: Thanks!  I still have a question, however, which is if I want to rerun MSE.  Specifically I would like to evaluate MSE at the end of each epoch on a validation set.  So how do I reset MSE so that the next time I run it it won't simply add/average MSE across all epochs?